# How do you generate your screenshot for deploying to app store

Tags: ios

To deploy your app on App store , you need provide screenshots.

I usually pressed the home + power button to get screenshot on my iphone 6

But is's really pain to generate other screenshot for different model 3.5" 4.0" 4.7" 5.5" screens

How do you generate this screenshots in an easier way?

Comment: There is no easy way. Run the app on each device (or corresponding simulator) and capture the desired screenshots. Yes, it's a pain. But you only need to do it once (initial release of the app) and maybe update then on a major update.

Comment: Most screenshots you see are from the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good answer, sadly. And it gets worse, since you're supposed to localise your screenshots if your app is.

Some people do it manually. Others use projects such as [snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot) or directly using UIAutomation to automate it, though doing this will take quite some time.

Also, you need to consider App Previews, which are even harder to automate.

Comment: I agree. In case anyone is interested in how to take screenshots on the iOS Simulator, simply click File > Save Screen Shot (⌘S)

Answer (score -1):

The "screenshots" for the app stores, in my opinion, should not be actual screenshots of screens, but a place in the app stores for you to advertise what your app is going to look and feel like, as well as what in will provide for the end user.

Making these images demonstrate what your app will be is essential, and they can contain more than simply screenshots of your app.

For example:

You can add the screenshot to a collage of marketing material to make your app store screenshots appear beautifully in the stores listing pages.

[AirBNB screenshots](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sommo.io%2Fblog%2Fapp-screenshots-for-the-apple-app-store-sizes-requirements-best-practices&psig=AOvVaw1nmsuclbuvIf-8QzzC5Z4A&ust=1701185754055000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjRxqFwoTCJDMvPfA5IIDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)

[Spotify screenshots](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2Fiosdev%2Fcomments%2Fbuh4zz%2Feasy_tool_for_creating_app_screenshots_in_all%2F&psig=AOvVaw1nmsuclbuvIf-8QzzC5Z4A&ust=1701185754055000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjRxqFwoTCJDMvPfA5IIDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP)

To answer the question,

Tools like [snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot) can help you take screenshots of your app to get the correct formatting for the images, and then you can impose these over your marketing creative in the following sizes for upload:

Required:

iPhone:

1290 x 2796px or 2796 x 1290px for 6.7"

1242 x 2688px, 2688 x 1242px, 1284 x 2778px or 2778 x 1284px for 6.5"

1242 x 2208px or 2208 x 1242px for 5.5"

Android:

Anything 9:16 or 16x9

You can include further screenshots for tablets as well, but it is not required

You should either create these directly in your mockup tool like photoshop, or use tools to create mock ups in the correct sizes

One of my favorites is [AppScreens](https://appscreens.com/), which will create great looking designs in all of the required format